# Deleting a file on the command promt does not work

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, uac

I want to programmatically delete all the files in some folders periodically. I tried to delete them with the "del" command and even with the /f option but the file just stays in place.

cmd.exe was launched with administrator rights (ctrl+shift and UAC dialog). I can't delete any of the files in these thumbs and grabs folders that are written by the security camera software iSpy Agent:

[screenshot of cmd window while trying to delete a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjuAu.jpg)

[del command with /F/Q/S options. Windows says "file deleted" but it is still there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d54A7.png)

```
Z:\CCTV\video\Hikvision-Carport\thumbs>DEL /F/Q/S 4_TimeLapse_2021-02-28_11-36-13.jpg
Datei wurde gelöscht - Z:\CCTV\video\Hikvision-Carport\thumbs\4_TimeLapse_2021-02-28_11-36-13.jpg

Z:\CCTV\video\Hikvision-Carport\thumbs>dir
 Datenträger in Laufwerk Z: ist WD 10TB Data
 Volumeseriennummer: 7CED-FAFA

 Verzeichnis von Z:\CCTV\video\Hikvision-Carport\thumbs

28.02.2021  12:42    <DIR>          .
28.02.2021  12:42    <DIR>          ..
28.02.2021  12:36             2’035 4_TimeLapse_2021-02-28_11-36-13.jpg
               1 Datei(en),          2’035 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 5’076’731’371’520 Bytes frei
```

I can delete the files just fine in the Windows file explorer.

The security settings of these files seem fine too:

[windows file security tab of the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80f77.png)

There is no error message after deleting the file fails.

What could cause this?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and share `attrib *.jpg` output (note that you can copy&paste _text_ from an open `cmd` window, no need to create screenshots).

Comment: What is the `Z:` drive? Is it on the network, and in that case with what permissions?

Comment: Z: is a local SATA harddisk drive.

Comment: @JosefZ I did copy the output.